# Detailed Capabilities Configuration for Custom Power BI Tree-Type Visual with Parent-Child Relationships and Data Retrieval

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm working on developing a custom Power BI visual in the form of a tree-type structure, and I'm facing challenges when trying to define and configure the capabilities for my specific case. The main objective is to model parent-child relationships between two tables, even though they might have different column names.

Context:

I have two data tables. Despite having distinct column names, there are common values that I want to use to establish a parent-child relationship between them.
The intention is to visualize the data in such a way that one table acts as the "parent" and displays information, while the other serves as its "child" with related data entries.

After matching a parent with its child, I wish to fetch specific data from the row of that matched child. To accomplish this, I intend to have another field in the capabilities where I can specify which columns to retrieve data from, once the matching between parent and child has occurred.

Capabilities Configuration:
In my capabilities.json, I've been experimenting with the dataViewMappings property. However, I've faced the following issues:

I'm only managing to retrieve one column at a time into my visual.
I've tried using both table and matrix structures in dataViewMappings, but neither seems to work as expected.

Here's a basic structure of what I've tried:

json

```
{
  "dataRoles": [...],
  "dataViewMappings": [
    {
      "table": {
        "rows": {
          "select": [...],
          "for": [...]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something or perhaps not structuring the capabilities correctly.

Has anyone tackled a similar challenge or could guide me on the nuances of setting up capabilities.json for parent-child table relationships in Power BI, especially when wanting to fetch data from specific columns post-match? Detailed examples or resources would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some sample dataset as per your requirement along with the snapshots of expected and current visual which is being rendered.
Also, you can refer to this documentation for achieving Parent-child relationship in Power BI Custom Visuals.
https://ck-corp.github.io/TreePowerBIVisual/